# Update Google IMA SDK for iOS 14 Privacy Policy for Swift

Tags: swift, idfa, google-ima, google-advertising-id

In iOS 14, you are required to update the Google IMA SDK to support tracking of advertisements.

It requires you to add a new function in order to request access to the user's IDFA:

```
func requestIDFA() {
 ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization(completionHandler: { status in
  // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.
  // loadAd()
  })
 }
```

When this function is called, it initiates a pop up that asks the user if they want to be tracked and gives the user the option to allow or disallow tracking.

The problem I'm having with the Google IMA SDK is i'm running a video pre-roll and when I test the updates for iOS 14 after when I choose "Do not track", i'm no longer able to produce a video preroll.

Does anyone have any insight into this? How can I still show video prerolls to users who choose to not be tracked?

Answer (score 0):

Most of ads buyers still leverage IDFA to target users as of today. Especially for high-valued video preroll ads, they really want to spend every cent of money on the right audience.

> How can I still show video prerolls to users who choose to not be tracked?

At this moment, Apple hasn't enforced developers to uses IDFA opt-in dialog. So without a doubt, ads buyers would still and stick to buying IDFA-enabled inventories.

The situation would defintely change after Apple changes their poloicy to make IDFA opt-in only.

I would suggest adding `SKAdNetwork` config in your `Info.plist`, following [Google's official instruction](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/ios/client-side/ios14#skadnetwork).